# Android JacocoReport task not executed

Tags: android, gradle, jacoco

I'm trying to get code coverage to work, but for some reason my registered jacoco task doesn't get executed.

I added this code to my modules build.gradle

```
tasks.register<JacocoReport>("randomTaskName") {
    println("Registering task")
    doFirst {
        println("First")
    }
    doLast {
        println("Last")
    }
}
```

Then I run ./gradlew shared:domain:randomTaskName

In log I can see:

```
Registering task
```

So "First" and "Last" parts are not called.

If I remove JacocoReport from tasks.register I get full log

```
Registering task

> Task :shared:domain:randomTaskName
First
Last
```

Why is this happening and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I was not specifying path for testDebugUnitTest.exec file.
What helped is adding --i to ./gradlew command. I then saw this line:

```
Skipping task ':shared:domain:randomTaskName' as task onlyIf is false.
```

Also make sure the path is correct. In my case it was under build/unit_test_code_coverage/debugUnitTest/testDebugUnitTest.exec